# Why is watch not reacting to changes of a property of an object in an Array of objects?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, watch

Consider the following (simplified) store. It holds an Array of "notes" (class objects):

```
// store.ts

import { reactive } from 'vue'
import { Note } from 'src/lib/note'

class Store {
  allNotes: Note[] = []
}
export const store = reactive(new Store())
```

I would like to watch `allNotes` for changes:

```
// note.ts

import { store } from 'src/lib/store'
    
watch(store.allNotes,
  (oldVal, newVal) => _.difference(newVal, oldVal)
    .forEach(note => {
      console.log("note changed")
    }),
  {deep: true}
)
```

When changing a specific note (a property of an element of `store.allNotes`) I do see the change in Chome DevTools Vue, but my watch does not trigger. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The  `reactive` properties aren't automatically unwrapped in the watch method (unlike `ref` ones), so you need to return them using a function `watch(()=>store.allNotes,...`  :

```js
watch(()=>store.allNotes,
  (oldVal, newVal) => _.difference(newVal, oldVal)
    .forEach(note => {
      console.log("note changed")
    }),
  {deep: true}
)
```

Comment: Thank you but this did not help. I will have to dig deeper to understand the lack of triggering upon changes - I thought that `deep` would be enough to monitor a property.

Comment: One question about that: the Array is reactive, but are its elements reactive as well (they are added though a `.push()`. Or should they be addedin a way that makes them reactive?